# Nginx ignores my second server directive

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration, reverse-proxy

I installed nginx via `apt-get install nginx` on ubuntu 14.04. As such, the default setup includes configs from the directory `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

In my conf.d folder I have the following two files (site1.conf and site2.conf)

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /site1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
}
```

and

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /site2/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
    }
}
```

When I visit `http://x.x.x.x/site1/`, I get the response from the server running at port 3000, as expected. When I visit `http://x.x.x.x/site2/`, however, I get a 404. In the error log, it says

```
2014/07/29 09:37:51 [error] 23060#0: *9 "/usr/share/nginx/html/site2/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 5.57.55.92, server: , request: "GET /site2/ HTTP/1.1", host: "217.147.85.96"
```

which indicates that it uses the default configuration, considering site2 to be a folder in which to find an index.html file.

Why is this so? I cannot find any reason why it would be so. I tried setting server_name for both configurations, but the made no difference.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `location` directives need to be in the same vhost configuration.

Different vhosts are meant to allow different host names and/or protocols to be served by the same server. What you have done effectively is to create two vhosts, but without a means to differentiate the two, e.g. with the `server_name` directive. Since it can't differentiate them, `nginx` just uses the first, default vhost configuration and tries to map the request, but since there is neither a directory called `site2` nor a `location` directive, it can't serve this.

Comment: That makes sense, actually. I just tried it out, and it works :) thanks